# TTS not work on chrome browser under ChromeDriver control

Tags: javascript, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Now I am using selenium + ChromeDriver to do webpage automation testing. This webpage includes one javascript using [Web Speech API](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/). The specified text can't be played under chrome driver control on Linux. I found the following difference w/o chromedirver.

If I start the chrome browser manually, and type the `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` on console, it can display one supported SpeechSynthesisVoice list. so the specified text can play with given voice.

But if I start the chrome browser by selenium + chrome driver, `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` on web console will show me nothing. So the specified text can't be played.

I tried to search this on google but unlucky, nothing related finding. Does anybody have the similar issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems nobody had the same issue but I found the solution under the help of chrome driver team.

I'd like to share the link solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/-ssKEYKu-dA